# __getitem__ method receives int instead of slice obj

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice, magic-methods

When implementing the `__getitem__` method in a custom class I expect the second argument to always be a slice obj.

However, when one execute `obj[i]` where `i` is an integer, `obj.__getitem__(self,value)` receives an `int` instead of a slice.

This can be tested doing

```
class MyClass:

    def __getitem__(self, sliceobj):
        print(type(sliceobj))

a = MyClass()

a[1:5]
a[2:]
a[::2]
a[0]

>> <class 'slice'>
>> <class 'slice'>
>> <class 'slice'>
>> <class 'int'>
```

This is causing me issues as my class has an internal list (defined in `__init__`) and I want to use the slice to iterate over it. The problem is that the output of `list[slice]` is not an iterable when `slice` is an `int`.

In other words:

```
class MyClass2:

    def __getitem__(self, sliceobj):

        a_list = [1,2,3,4]

        print(sliceobj)

        for val in a_list[sliceobj]:
            # do stuff
            pass

        print('it worked')

a = MyClass2()

a[1:3]
a[2:]
a[::2]
a[0]
```

works for the first 3 calls, but it doesn't for the last, as `a_list[0]` is not iterable.

Shouldn't `a[0]` be translated in `a.__getitem__(slice(0,1))` (that would work) ?

Comment: At the moment the only solution i found is to add `if isinstance(sliceobj, int): sliceobj= slice(sliceobj, sliceobj+1)` to the `__getitem__` method

Comment: If `a[x]` were translated to `a[x:x+1]`, how would you ever get the value actually stored at that position, rather than another list that contains the value?

Comment: @chepner you are right. That would make access to the value impossible. Didn't think about that (as in my case that is not required, but it obviously is in most other cases)

Comment: Once upon a time (in Python 2), there were separate methods `__getitem__` and `__getslice__`. At some point (probably at or around the time new-style classes were created), the `slice` type was added so that both methods could be merged into a single `__getitem__` method. `__getslice__` was deprecated and formally removed in Python 3.

Comment: Note that the slicing syntax can also generate a *tuple* of `slice` objects: `a[1:3, 2:]` would desugar to `a.__getitem__((slice(1,3), slice(2,None))`. This was added specifically for NumPy, though no built-in type supports the resulting tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

> For sequence types, the accepted keys should be **integers and slice objects**

You can check if the key is a slice or not and create one:

```
class MyClass2:
    def __getitem__(self, key):

        a_list = [1,2,3,4]
        keys_to_iterate = key if isinstance(key, slice) else slice(key, key+1)
        print(key)

        for val in a_list[keys_to_iterate]:
            # do stuff
            pass

        print('it worked')
```

Running example: https://repl.it/repls/SmallDarkblueWifi